# Custom DFT function returns the complex conjugate of what it should

Tags: python, numpy, dft

I'm trying to write a custom function that finds the nth discrete Fourier transform matrix, as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) (except without dividing by `sqrt(N)`). I've succeeded in getting the nth root of unity, but for some reason, when I multiply it into a matrix, I'm getting the complex conjugate of what I expect. You can see this by comparing the output of my function with the output of `sp.fft(np.eye(n))` (they should match):

```
import numpy as np, scipy as sp    

def dftmat(n):

    # nth root of unity
    # w = complex(np.cos(2*np.pi / n), np.sin(2*np.pi / n))
    w = np.exp(2j * np.pi / n)

    # bind its powers into a matrix
    F = np.matrix([ [w**(a*b) for a in range(n)] for b in range(n)])
    return(F)


a = np.round(dftmat(6),3)
b = np.round(sp.fft(sp.eye(6)),3)
print(a)
print(b)
```

yields

```
[[ 1. +0.j     1. +0.j     1. +0.j     1. +0.j     1. +0.j     1. +0.j   ]
 [ 1. +0.j     0.5+0.866j -0.5+0.866j -1. +0.j    -0.5-0.866j  0.5-0.866j]
 [ 1. +0.j    -0.5+0.866j -0.5-0.866j  1. -0.j    -0.5+0.866j -0.5-0.866j]
 [ 1. +0.j    -1. +0.j     1. -0.j    -1. +0.j     1. -0.j    -1. +0.j   ]
 [ 1. +0.j    -0.5-0.866j -0.5+0.866j  1. -0.j    -0.5-0.866j -0.5+0.866j]
 [ 1. +0.j     0.5-0.866j -0.5-0.866j -1. +0.j    -0.5+0.866j  0.5+0.866j]]
[[ 1. +0.j     1. +0.j     1. +0.j     1. +0.j     1. +0.j     1. +0.j   ]
 [ 1. +0.j     0.5-0.866j -0.5-0.866j -1. +0.j    -0.5+0.866j  0.5+0.866j]
 [ 1. +0.j    -0.5-0.866j -0.5+0.866j  1. +0.j    -0.5-0.866j -0.5+0.866j]
 [ 1. +0.j    -1. +0.j     1. +0.j    -1. +0.j     1. +0.j    -1. +0.j   ]
 [ 1. +0.j    -0.5+0.866j -0.5-0.866j  1. -0.j    -0.5+0.866j -0.5-0.866j]
 [ 1. +0.j     0.5+0.866j -0.5+0.866j -1. -0.j    -0.5-0.866j  0.5-0.866j]]
```

I thought that the problem might have to do with the way I set up the list comprehension defining `F`, but removing the `w**` from that line appears to produce the correct set of exponents:

```
n = 6
F = np.matrix([ [(a*b) for a in range(n)] for b in range(n)])
print(F)
```

yields

```
[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 0  2  4  6  8 10]
 [ 0  3  6  9 12 15]
 [ 0  4  8 12 16 20]
 [ 0  5 10 15 20 25]]
```

[Here's a TIO link.](https://tio.run/##lU/NaoQwED6bpxjoJRGxsAt7KPTqSyx7iJp0U@pkSEbUp7ejtrRLTz1l5pvvL7TwPeJ5DQPFxIDjQAvYDEgV5C4cS6a1dx56z4NljeZFqeIJkO@QYmSIHkYMvGzgBK/QxYE@3KyR6i5mfSploADPgKYS4zoHfACNKjaZAG4mfXqHEn6Oe1QbsIfAGShOLmUIyBEsSJsUZlU0h/pY9RWuU1lqW7YGfEzCCwjJ4puT6rcdah8gyU@Ox4S6kThlD7cUR@z1158vpjob1f6@ZKq95@1xixPCzqAk1bT9HlrxQxFd1J@K/@p3uDVmXT8B) Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: F could also be generated using `np.outer()` or `np.meshgrid()`.

Comment: You missed the minus in the exponent of ω, which means you're effectively rotating the other way around, which yields the conjugate.

Comment: @blubberdiblub That'll do it. Thank you.